# Back Up for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, backup, store

Need some advice from anybody who knows.We have a client website that is wordpress ecommerce and it is huge. too big for backup buddy. to back up. To do so manually takes virtually a day. what else is available to do good Scheduled backups for ecommerce sites, so people don't lose the info if it gets hacked etc.. or keeps an up to date backup if it has constant changes. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updraft Pus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/) can be used for backups and migrations. Files are compressed and stored on the server for quick recovery and also can be downloaded or uploaded to remote storage. Allows you to choose what to backup too, plugins, uploads, database, themes. Has a scheduled backup feature too.

Not sure if it will work for your site though, depending on how large your site is. It's free so you could try and see how long it takes to back it up. I've used it on some large client sites and it performs well.

Comment: thank you for your attention I am trying updraft plus now.. I will notify you if it will work..

Answer (score 0):

If you have console access to the mysql server, just use mysqldump and setup a task. I suggest using Amazon RDS, you can set them to make nightly backups for you automatically in the configuration process.

backup:

```
mysqldump -h hostname -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

restore:

```
mysql -h hostname -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```